# mshtml ocx and https page causing x-frame-options trigger?

Tags: internet-explorer, vb6, mshtml, x-frame-options

I have inherited an application that uses the MSHTML trident library to grab a web page inside of a vb6 dll.

The error is this: I am trying to browse to an https site using the control. No matter what https site I try to go to, the result is the same... an Internet Explorer iframe embedding error.

**"To help protect the security of information you enter into this website, the publisher of this content does not allow it to be displayed in a frame."**

Here is the minimum code I can use to get the error

```
Dim oHTML As New HTMLDocument, oDoc As HTMLDocument
Set oDoc = oHTML.createDocumentFromUrl("https://www.google.com", "")
```

I have used fiddler proxy to filter the x-frame-options from the header of the https site, and it then works perfectly well.

Note: this doesn't seem to follow any logic. The page works perfectly well in internet explorer when I use the same urls, but once embedded they fail to work at all.

Some more info: This is working on an older system that has a really old ie.

I also set up an iis site that has this header enabled but only returns raw text, No HTML at all, back to the vb6 dll. This also fails.

Additional info:
Internet Explorer 10
Windows 7
vb6

I have tried fugding all kinds of xss, iframe and registry compat settings to no avail. Please help!

Comment: I would suggest you rethink your approach. This error message is to prevent cross-site scripting and general hackery. What are you actually trying to do? Why do you need to use an IFrame?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I think you mis-understand. There is no iframe in this picture, but for some reason ie's frame clickjack protection is kicking in. If you create a vb6 app with just those above lines of code, it still happens